# rename an element with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, parameters, xml-namespaces

I have this xml:

```
<pos:getPositionRouter xmlns:pos="positionNS">
   <positionID>
      <code>1</code>
   </positionID>
   <parameter>?</parameter>
</pos:getPositionRouter>
```

and I want to rename the element `pos:getPositionRouter` to `x:getPosition` using xslt:

```
<x:getPosition xmlns:x="newPositionNS">
   <positionID>
      <code>1</code>
   </positionID>
   <parameter>?</parameter>
</x:getPosition>
```

This is the sylesheet I came up with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

 <xsl:param name="old_namespace" />
 <xsl:param name="old_element_localname" />
 <xsl:param name="new_namespace" />
 <xsl:param name="new_element_localname" />


 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="(local-name() = $old_element_localname) and (namespace-uri() = $old_namespace)">
    <xsl:element name="{$new_element_localname}" namespace="{$new_namespace}">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
   </xsl:when>

   <!-- copy the rest as is -->
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am forced to use xalan as xslt processor, and the output, unfortunately is this:

```
<getPosition xmlns="newPositionNS">
   <positionID xmlns:pos="positionNS">
      <code>1</code>
   </positionID>
   <parameter xmlns:pos="positionNS">?</parameter>
</getPosition>
```

The default namespace of the `getPosition` element becomes the new namespace, but the child elements should remain without namespace (`xmlns=""`).

Can someone understand why?

Thank you!

Comment: Do note that your desired output and your actual output are semantically equal: `{newPositionNS}getPosition` children are under null namespace URI, they just have a "positionNS" namespace URI in scope (but not used).

Comment: Hello Alejandro, as I understand it, the two outputs are not semantically equal: the default namespace setting xmlns="newPositionNS" on the root element is inherited to the childs, so positionID is now in the newPositionNS namespace, and not in the "" namespace as it should.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and simple solution. :)

Comment: But that is not the output I get from your transformation: `<getPosition xmlns="newPositionNS"><positionID xmlns:pos="positionNS" xmlns=""><code>1</code></positionID><parameter xmlns:pos="positionNS" xmlns="">?</parameter></getPosition>`

Comment: Alejandro, the output I get is the one I posted. There is no xmlns="" in my output. What version of xalan are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="old_namespace" select="'positionNS'"/>
    <xsl:param name="old_element_localname" select="'getPositionRouter'"/>
    <xsl:param name="new_namespace_prefix" select="'x'"/>
    <xsl:param name="new_namespace" select="'newPositionNS'"/>
    <xsl:param name="new_element_localname" select="'getPosition'" />
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="local-name()=$old_element_localname and
                            namespace-uri()=$old_namespace">
                <xsl:element
                     name="{substring(concat($new_namespace_prefix,':'),
                                      1 div boolean($new_namespace_prefix))}{
                            $new_element_localname}"
                     namespace="{$new_namespace}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<x:getPosition xmlns:x="newPositionNS">
    <positionID>
        <code>1</code>
    </positionID>
    <parameter>?</parameter>
</x:getPosition>
```

**Note**: If you want an specific prefix you should add it to the QName. If you want to remove in-scope namespace you shouldn't use `xsl:copy` in XSLT 1.0

Comment: Awesome, thank you Alejandro, I don't really want to force the namespace prefix, the 'x' was just an example, but it could be anything, that is not important. The important thing is that the child elements don't have a namespace.

Comment: @Luca: You are wellcome. Check my comment to your quentions. Maybe you should report a bug in Xalan.

Answer (score 0):

**I. The transformation to do this without using parameters is really short and simple**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:pos="positionNS" xmlns:x="newPositionNS" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="pos:getPositionRouter">
  <xsl:element name="x:getPosition">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name()='pos')]"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<pos:getPositionRouter xmlns:pos="positionNS">
   <positionID>
      <code>1</code>
   </positionID>
   <parameter>?</parameter>
</pos:getPositionRouter>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<x:getPosition xmlns:x="newPositionNS">
    <positionID>
        <code>1</code>1
    </positionID>
    <code>1</code>1
    <parameter>?</parameter>?
</x:getPosition>
```

II. **The parameterized transformation is just a little bit more complex**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pOldNamespace"  select="'positionNS'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pOldElementLocalname"  select="'getPositionRouter'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pNewNamespace"  select="'newPositionNS'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pNewElementLocalname"  select="'getPosition'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pNewElementPrefix"  select="'x'"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:variable name="vReplacing" select=
  "local-name()=$pOldElementLocalname
  and
    namespace-uri()=$pOldNamespace"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vName">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$vReplacing">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat($pNewElementPrefix, ':', local-name())"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="vNamespace">
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$vReplacing">
     <xsl:value-of select="$pNewNamespace"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select="namespace-uri()"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:element name="{$vName}" namespace="{$vNamespace}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(.=$pOldNamespace)]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Dimitre: Besides that parametrization was a request, and the good method for striping only an specific in-scope namespace, I think you should recheck your stylesheet: applying to attributes without attribute rule and an `<xsl:apply-templates/>` typo in "any element" rule.

Comment: @Alejandro: I know well that I missed attributes -- intentionally, as there are no attributes in the source XML. As for the parameterization -- it can be only seen in the provided code, which I did not bother to read at all... I am not sure that parameterization is a requirement.

Comment: +1 I like the variable declaration for name and namespace, makes the stylesheet more readable.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre to you as well. Just to answer: the parameters for element name and namespace are needed, I don't want to make a new stylesheet for every element I want to rename :)

Comment: @Luca: Yes, I realized that and have now added a parameterized solution -- do take a look at it.